# Lipschitz function and differentiabily

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove this:

$U \subset \Bbb R^n$. Let $f:U\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function. Then

$\exists \;k\in\Bbb R, k\neq 0$ so that $\mid df_a(v)\mid \leq k \parallel v\parallel \;\forall \;a\in U, \forall \; v \in \Bbb R^n$ $\iff$ $f$ is Lipschitz

I haven't really tried much since I don't know where to start.

Comment: I think you might want $k \in R$, not $k \in R^n$.

Comment: To get an idea of how the proof should go, first try proving it for $n=1$.  For one direction, use the definition of derivative.  For the other direction, use the mean value theorem.

Comment: OK, I've proven it for $n=1$ and also this side $\implies$ of the implication, but I can't do the other one...

Comment: I got the other side too. Thanks!